# Is it a good idea to use Twitter Bootstrap 3 for production?

Tags: web-development

So in the past few weeks I was introduced to Bootstrap 3-RC1. I made some web sites using it, and I actually enjoyed it. Then, recently, I discovered Twitter Bootstrap has already released version 3-RC2. It makes me wonder if it's okay for me to use Bootstrap RC2 for production now? Is it wise if I used it considering it still in RC phase or should I just wait for the official, completed version 3?

Comment: Migrating it down the road could be a pain - wait for the official release.

Comment: What sort of timeline do you have for taking your project live?

Comment: -1 and no comment...

Comment: i have to release the web maybe in 1-2 months @SeanMcSomething

Comment: While I didn't down vote, I can see why someone would.  You're asking if a release candidate is okay to use for production code. That's not an on-topic question for the site. The only authoritative source on safe-to-use for production use would the terms of use wrapped around the RC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Release candidates are usually [well tested, with no major bugs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_release_life_cycle#Release_candidate).

Really it comes down to your specific company or project and their attitude to risk and where you are in your projects release cycle.

6 months before your release and you're probably going to be able fit in an upgrade to the full v3 release, but if you only have a week to go maybe you wouldn't want to risk it.

Comment: well what do you know, the final release of v3 is official now, thanks for the answer though

Comment: New post - "Is it a good idea to use Twitter Bootstrap 3.0.0 for production?"

Comment: Indeed. My answer can be applied to grand new full releases as well.